# Environment variables for the file config.asy

Tags: asymptote

Of course, I understand that this question is not on the topic of this forum, but nevertheless about this topic is also asked and it happens even that they get answers to these questions. So I will ask. Look, please, here's the [question](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=32829). If anyone knows anything about this issue, please write.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, don't just link another question. If the link dies you question will be rendered useless. Copy the relevant parts of the linked post here, please.

Comment: OK.  Here: https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/11ef82fe/?limit=25#8e0b/70d1 are some environment variables whose values ​​can be specified in the config.asy file. Another such variable is mentioned here: https://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349/thread/95364762/?limit=25#286d/d70c - python. It seems that this is not the whole list of such variables. And where is a complete list of such variables?

Answer (score 2):

Rephrasing the question as

> Where is a complete list  of environment variables  whose values can
>   be specified in the `config.asy` file?

Most likely, the whole list can be found in 
the source file `settings.cc`, 
where corresponding lines 
for the `Asymptote` version 2.59 are:

```
addOption(new envSetting("config","config."+suffix));
addOption(new envSetting("htmlviewer", defaultHTMLViewer));
addOption(new envSetting("pdfviewer", defaultPDFViewer));
addOption(new envSetting("psviewer", defaultPSViewer));
addOption(new envSetting("gs", defaultGhostscript));
addOption(new envSetting("libgs", defaultGhostscriptLibrary));
addOption(new envSetting("epsdriver", defaultEPSdriver));
addOption(new envSetting("asygl", defaultAsyGL));
addOption(new envSetting("texpath", ""));
addOption(new envSetting("texcommand", ""));
addOption(new envSetting("dvips", "dvips"));
addOption(new envSetting("dvisvgm", "dvisvgm"));
addOption(new envSetting("convert", "convert"));
addOption(new envSetting("display", defaultDisplay));
addOption(new envSetting("animate", defaultAnimate));
addOption(new envSetting("papertype", "letter"));
addOption(new envSetting("dir", ""));
addOption(new envSetting("sysdir", systemDir));
addOption(new envSetting("textcommand","groff"));
addOption(new envSetting("textcommandOptions","-e -P -b16"));
addOption(new envSetting("textextension", "roff"));
addOption(new envSetting("textoutformat", "ps"));
addOption(new envSetting("textprologue", ".EQ\ndelim $$\n.EN"));
addOption(new envSetting("textinitialfont", ".fam T\n.ps 12"));
addOption(new envSetting("textepilogue", ".bp"));
```

Also, as the main asymptote doc says, the function

```
list("settings");
```

will list all global variables defined 
in a module `settings`, which for the same version is

```
int historylines;
bool animating;
real zoomstep;
bool wait;
bool pdfreload;
string command;
bool safe;
bool globalwrite;
int pdfreloaddelay;
string pdfreloadOptions;
bool autobillboard;
int level;
string gs;
int inpipe;
bool xasy;
string texcommand;
bool tabcompletion;
real resizestep;
string htmlviewer;
string asygl;
real vibrateTime;
string htmlviewerOptions;
string textcommand;
int antialias;
string libgs;
int scroll;
bool fitscreen;
string dvisvgm;
string textcommandOptions;
string outname;
string dvisvgmOptions;
bool where;
string textoutformat;
string align;
bool autoplay;
bool autoplain;
pair aligndir;
pair maxtile;
string outformat;
bool compact;
string textprologue;
string textepilogue;
string textextension;
string tex;
int digits;
bool threads;
bool bw;
bool svgemulation;
bool twosided;
bool inlinetex;
pair position;
string config;
string prompt;
bool inlineimage;
string prompt2;
string sysdir;
string convert;
bool thin;
bool parseonly;
string pdfviewer;
bool prc;
bool autorotate;
int outpipe;
string convertOptions;
string pdfviewerOptions;
string[] middlebutton;
bool envmap;
bool batchView;
bool exitonEOF;
string display;
bool keepaux;
bool batchMask;
bool debug;
string user;
string papertype;
real paperwidth;
real paperheight;
bool localhistory;
int verbose;
string dvips;
bool embed;
bool listvariables;
real spinstep;
bool multiline;
string dvipsOptions;
int multisample;
bool absolute;
bool multipleView;
bool reverse;
bool quiet;
bool toolbar;
bool thick;
string autoimport;
bool interrupt;
string hyperrefOptions;
bool interactiveView;
bool interactiveWrite;
string glOptions;
bool interactiveMask;
string[] rightbutton;
bool keep;
real framerate;
real render;
real framedelay;
string textinitialfont;
bool iconify;
pair viewportmargin;
bool auto3D;
bool offscreen;
string psviewer;
bool axes3;
bool loop;
string gsOptions;
string psviewerOptions;
bool gray;
real shiftWaitTime;
bool translate;
real zoomfactor;
string[] wheelup;
real shiftHoldDistance;
string[] wheeldown;
string[] suppress;
string[] leftbutton;
real zoomPinchCap;
string texpath;
pair maxviewport;
real zoomPinchFactor;
bool offline;
bool rgb;
string epsdriver;
bool cmyk;
string dir;
string animate;
bool twice;
pair offset;
```

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where this file is located on the windows? For some reason, even a search all over the computer did not give anything.

Comment: @mathem: The source files most probably are not included in the binary installation, 
but they can be found at 
[Sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/asymptote/files/2.59/asymptote-2.59.src.tgz/download).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers